# How to access other module data table SugarCRM

Tags: hook, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am writing logic hook and I need to update 1 module fields by using other module elements.

```php
<?php
class logic_hooks_class {

function after_save_method($bean, $event, $arguments) {

    if (!isset($bean->ignore_update_c)||$bean->ignore_update_c === false {

     //here I need to get module's reservations element: amount_reserved 
     //should I load relationship like $bean->load_relationship('reservations'); ??
     //need to set total_reserved = amount_reserved;
     //by the way amount_reserved might have several values for one reserved

          $bean->goods = $bean->amount-$bean->total_reserved;
          $bean->ignore_update_c = true;
          $bean->save();
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: i did not understand the problem properly , assuming that you need to update a field of module based on other module field , if that is the scenario than you can make use of this method : get_linked_beans(); in your hook , it worked for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the beans for the relationship like this:

```
$bean->load_relationship('reservations');
$reservations = $bean->reservations->getBeans();
```

Now one can loop the `$reservations` and `fetch` and sum up the wanted value.

Just to clarify how `load_relationship` works. The parameter for `load_relationship` should be the link vardef pointing to the name of the relationship. A logical name is the plural name for the module, like reservations.